# TikZ: punctured point for function with a gap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to create a graph of a function with gap and make the upper point punctured, like on picture below. Is there any way to do this other than to manually create a little circle and try to adjust the above line to fit?

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={sigma(\x)=1/(1+exp(-\x));}]
    \begin{axis}
    [
        grid=major,     
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        axis x line=bottom,
        ytick={0,.5,1},
        ymax=1,
        axis y line=middle,
        samples=100,
        domain=-6:6,
        legend style={at={(1,0.9)}}     
    ]
        \draw [dashed,black!50] (1,0.365) -- (1,0.865);
        \addplot[very thick,black,mark=none, samples=100,domain=-6:1]   (x, {.5 * sigma(x)});
        \addplot[very thick,black,mark=none, samples=100,domain=1:6]   (x, {.5 + .5 * sigma(x)});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe I do not understand the question, but `\path (1,0.865) node[draw, circle, inner sep=2pt]{};` is not sufficient?

Comment: \draw (axis cs:1,0.865) circle (2pt);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quite understand what you mean by adjusting a line to fit, but I would declare a function and use that to draw everything -- the plots, the dashed line and the circle.

It's possible to have `pgfplots` draw a marker at only the first point, by setting `mark repeat=N`, where `N` is some number bigger than or equal to the number of samples. Hence, you can do

```
\addplot[very thick,black,mark=*,mark options={fill=white},domain=1:6, mark repeat=1000]  {F(x)+0.5};
```

to draw the second half including the marker. `F` is a function declared with `declare function`, see code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
           sigma(\x)=1/(1+exp(-\x));
           F(\x) = 0.5 * sigma(\x);
           }]
    \begin{axis}
    [
        grid=major,     
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        axis x line=bottom,
        ytick={0,.5,1},
        ymax=1,
        axis y line=middle,
        samples=100,
        legend style={at={(1,0.9)}}     
    ]
        \addplot[very thick,black,mark=none, domain=-6:1]   {F(x)};
        \addplot[very thick,black,mark=*,mark options={fill=white},domain=1:6, mark repeat=1000]    {F(x)+0.5};

        \draw [dashed,black!50] (1,{F(1)}) -- (1,{F(1)+0.5});        
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also to the dashed line and the circle in the same go: `\addplot[dashed, black!50, mark=*, mark options={fill=white,thick, draw=black,solid}, mark phase=2]   coordinates {(1,{F(1)})(1,{F(1)+0.5})};`

Comment: Well I meant maybe there was some way to automatically create a marker on the end of the line, but I see this is not the case

Comment: @MandaloreUltimate Actually there might be, I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: @MandaloreUltimate Assuming 100 samples, you can use `mark repeat=100` (or some higher value): `\addplot[very thick,black,mark=*,mark options={fill=white},domain=1:6, mark repeat=100]    {F(x)+0.5};`. Then you get a mark only every 100th data point, i.e. only the first point.

Comment: @MandaloreUltimate Not entirely automatic, but a bit better.